# Проблема с Gson

Tags: android

Почему-то ругается `Gson`, библиотеки добавил как следует.. почему не видит еклипс его?

```
06-13 06:34:05.279: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.Gson
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at com.example.asd.GetSend.requestGET(GetSend.java:63)
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at com.example.asd.GetSend.doInBackground(GetSend.java:88)
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at com.example.asd.GetSend.doInBackground(GetSend.java:1)
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-13 06:34:58.468: E/AndroidRuntime(880):  ... 5 more
```

Comment: Вы ведь положили все зависимости в директорию libs проекта?

Comment: абсолютно все

Comment: Не оно? [ADT r22 и noClasDefFoundException][1]


  [1]: http://http://expedition107.blogspot.ru/2013/06/adt-r22-noclasdeffoundexception.html